# Java unbounded for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

> Unbounded loop: where number of times its body repeats is unknown in
>   advance.   • e.g. repeat until the user types "q" to quit.

This is the explaination of an unbounded for loop. I don't understand it, could someone maybe give me an example? Thanks in advance

Comment: `for(;;);` = Unbounded for-loop that does nothing. Or to go with the example `for(;;) if (((char)System.in.read()) == 'q') break;`

Comment: A bounded loop can execute a number of times that is unknown in advance, for example `for (int i = 0, m = new Random().nextInt(10); i < m; ++i);`.

Comment: It's a computer science thing: If you want to find out why anybody cares whether a loop is _bounded_ or not, then a good place to start would be to read about the "BlooP" and "FlooP" programming languages invented by Douglas Hofstadter.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlooP_and_FlooP

Answer (score 1):

look, in `for` loop, you can set the counter and when it reaches the loop end conditions, such as `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)`.
If you need unbounded loop (when you do not know how many iterations you need, but you have some conditions for its completion), you can set the following condition:

```
for ( ; ; ) {
   if (condition == true) exit from loop;
}
```

or using `while` loop, I think that's better for unbounded.

Comment: I am not a guy that will look at bytecode. But actually, I *guess* it will be optimized to the same bytecode if you use for(;;) with break on condition or while. At least I'd expect so.

Answer (score 0):

A bounded loop is a loop with a known iteration count, like :

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

}
```

As you see, you're guaranteed (unless something like some `Exception` or a `break` statement occurs), that there will be 10 iterations.

An unbounded loop has no bounds, you can't tell in advance how many iterations there will be , like :

```
boolean exit = false;

while(!exit){

 // set exit to true to stop looping
}
```

Or like the example from @Fildor, a `for` loop with no ending condition.
Note that this loop is infinite until like said above, a `break` statement or some exception occur (this loop is similar to `while(true)` ) :

```
for(;;)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is code that does exactly what the definition you posted describes. It just means that when the programmer is typing the code there is no knowledge of the amount of times the body of the while loop will run.

```
BufferedReader br = null;

try {

    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    while (true) {

        System.out.print("Enter something : ");
        String input = br.readLine();

        if ("q".equals(input)) {
            System.out.println("Exit!");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        System.out.println("input : " + input);
        System.out.println("-----------\n");
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (br != null) {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Code from: [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-input-from-console-java/)

Answer (score 0):

Unbound loops can also be due to logical errors:

Example:

```
int i;
for(i=0;i!=i+1;++i){
    //System.out.println(i);
}
System.out.println(i); // never prints
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Class {

  public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    int count = 0;
    for (char c = ' '; c != 'q'; c = (char) System.in.read()) {
      System.out.println("current value of c: " + c);
      System.out.println("Number of keystrokes so far: " + count++);
    }
  }
}
```